# Simple console lotto game c# match arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, console-application

I'm trying to make a simple lotto/bingo game in c#.

Trying to make something like this:

Game where user types in 10 numbers which gets stored to an array.

Then the game makes a "lotto card" which is a 2 dimensional array with random numbers, like this:

- 10 | 13 | 14 | 17 | 16
- 18 | 24 | 21 | 23 | 8
- 1 | 3  | 6  | 25 | 9
- 7  | 22 | 15 | 12 | 2
- 4  |  5 | 11 | 19 | 20

Now i want to compare the contents of both arrays. I cant seem to find a way to do this with both 1 and 2 dimensionall arrays? Right now i've only managed to check if one of the numbers match.

Have tried using Linq and enumerabl and different loops in a couple of ways but with no success.

I want the game to register bingo if i match the numbers horizontally, vertically and diagonally.

This is my code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Greet and explain the rules
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to bingo!");

        
        string input; // Variabel for input by user
        int inputnmr; // Variabel for nmrinput by user
        int low = 1;
        int high = 25;

        int[] userNmr = new int[7]; // Creates a new array for the player


        // Loop - asks user to type in their lotto numbers and stores them in variable "userNmr"
        for (int i = 0; i < userNmr.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Type in a number between {0} - {1}:", low, high);
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            inputnmr = int.Parse(input);
            userNmr[i] = inputnmr;

        }

        //Prints your lotto numbers:
        Console.Write("These are your numbers :");
        foreach (int i in userNmr)
        {
            Console.Write(i);
            Console.Write(", ");
        }

        //Asks if continue:
        Console.WriteLine("Are you sure about your numbers?");
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want a bingo card?");


        int x = 5; // Variable for size of x-axis
        int y = 5; //Variable for the size of y-axis

        //Variable for 2 dimensional array:
        int[,] lottoCard = new int[x, y];
                 
        //Create random
        Random randomnmr = new Random();

        //Prints the lotto cards x-axis
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {


            Console.WriteLine(" |------------------------|");
            Console.Write(" | ");

            //Prints the lotto card y-axis
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                //Fills lotto card with random ints:
                lottoCard[i, j] = randomnmr.Next(1, 26);
                Console.Write(lottoCard[i, j] + " | ");

            }

            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" |------------------------|");

        //  --- This is where im stuck --- 

        bool oneMatch = false;
        while (oneMatch == false)
        {
            foreach (var numberA in userNmr)
            {
                foreach (var numberB in lottoCard)
                {
                    if (numberA == numberB)
                    {
                        oneMatch = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (oneMatch == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BINGO!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No win . . .");
        }
```

Things i've tried:

```
1:

bool equal = lottoCard.Rank == userNmr.Rank && Enumerable.Range(0, lottoCard.Rank).All(dimension => lottoCard.GetLength(dimension) == lottoCard.GetLength(dimension)) && lottoCard.Cast<double>().SequenceEqual(lottoCard.Cast<double>());
if (equal == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bingo");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("no win");
}


2: 

bool IsContain(int[][] lottoCard, int[] userNmr)
{
    foreach (int[] row in lottoCard)
    {
        int curlIndex = 0;
        foreach (int item in row)
        {
            if (item == userNmr[curlIndex])
            {

                if (curlIndex == userNmr.Length - 1)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                curlIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                curlIndex = 0;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}

if (IsContain(lottoCard, userNmr))
{
    Console.WriteLine("BINGO");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No win");
}
```

**Above does not work, would really appreciate some help!**

Comment: "Game where user types in 10 numbers which gets stored to an array."  Can you explain more how those 10 numbers correspond to a "win" in a  5 (wide) x 4 (tall) matrix? Do you simply want to enumerate all rows (5 nums), columns (4 nums), diagonals (4 nums) and see if the values from those sequences are all present within the 10 numbers typed in by the user?

Comment: Your code seems to be making a 5x5 bingo card while your description shows a 5x4 bingo card.  Which is it?

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad! Should be 5x5 bingo card.  If the numbers in userNmr match the 2d "bingoCard" array - 5 in a row. Problem is i can't figure out how to compare the 1d array with the 2d array

Comment: Is it okay that your current Bingo card generator can produce a card with duplicate numbers?

Comment: Well... That's another problem actually. But I think the solution for that may be to make it so the bingo card holds the numbers from 1 - 25, and then shuffle it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would have done it:

```
class Program
{        

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Bingo!");

        int[] userNmr = getUserInput();
        int[,] bingoCard = genBingoCard();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Your number selections are:");
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", userNmr));

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Here is your Bingo Card!");
        displayBingoCard(bingoCard);

        bool bingo = checkForBingo(userNmr, bingoCard);
        if (bingo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You had a Bingo!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, no Bingos. Better luck next time!");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Quit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static int[] getUserInput()
    {
        int low = 1;
        int high = 25;
        string input;
        int inputnmr;
        int[] userNmr = new int[7];

        // Loop - asks user to type in their lotto numbers and stores them in variable "userNmr"
        bool valid;
        for (int i = 0; i < userNmr.Length; i++)
        {
            valid = false;
            while (!valid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("User Selection #" + (i + 1));
                Console.Write("Select a number between {0} - {1}: ", low, high);
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (int.TryParse(input, out inputnmr))
                {
                    if (inputnmr >= low && inputnmr <= high)
                    {
                        if (!userNmr.Contains(inputnmr))
                        {
                            userNmr[i] = inputnmr;
                            valid = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("You already picked that number!");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Number must be between {0} and {1}!", low, high);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Number.");
                }
            }
        }
        return userNmr;
    }

    public static int[,] genBingoCard()
    {
        Random randomnmr = new Random();

        int x = 5; // Variable for size of x-axis
        int y = 5; //Variable for the size of y-axis

        //Variable for 2 dimensional array:
        int[,] bingoCard = new int[y, x];
        List<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, x * y).ToList();
        numbers = numbers.OrderBy(z => randomnmr.Next()).ToList();

        int counter = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < y; r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < x; c++)
            {
                bingoCard[r, c] = numbers[counter++];
            }
        }
        return bingoCard;
    }

    public static void displayBingoCard(int[,] bingoCard)
    {
        int x = bingoCard.GetUpperBound(1) + 1; // Variable for size of x-axis
        int y = bingoCard.GetUpperBound(0) + 1; //Variable for the size of y-axis
        string line = "";
        for (int c = 0; c < x; c++)
        {
            line = line + "+----";
        }
        line = line + "+";

        Console.WriteLine(line);
        for (int r = 0; r < y; r++)
        {
            Console.Write("|");
            for (int c = 0; c < x; c++)
            {
                Console.Write(" " + bingoCard[r, c].ToString("00") + " |");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }

    public static bool checkForBingo(int[] userNmr, int[,] bingoCard)
    {
        int x = bingoCard.GetUpperBound(1) + 1; // Variable for size of x-axis
        int y = bingoCard.GetUpperBound(0) + 1; //Variable for the size of y-axis

        bool bingo;
        // check each row
        for (int r = 0; r < y; r++)
        {
            bingo = true; // until proven otherwise
            for (int c = 0; c < x && bingo; c++)
            {
                int number = bingoCard[r, c];
                bingo = userNmr.Contains(number);
            }
            if (bingo)
            {           
                Console.WriteLine("Horizontal Bingo at Row: " + (r+1));         
                return true;
            }
        }

        // check each column
        for (int c = 0; c < x; c++)
        {
            bingo = true; // until proven otherwise
            for (int r = 0; r < y && bingo; r++)
            {
                int number = bingoCard[r, c];
                bingo = userNmr.Contains(number);
            }
            if (bingo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Vertical Bingo at Column: " + (c+1));         
                return true;
            }
        }

        // check diagonals
        // top left to bottom right
        bingo = true; // until proven otherwise
        for (int c = 0; c < x && bingo; c++)
        {                
            for (int r = 0; r < y && bingo; r++)
            {
                int number = bingoCard[r, c];
                bingo = userNmr.Contains(number);
            }                
        }
        if (bingo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Diagonal Bingo from Top Left to Bottom Right.");         
            return true;
        }
        // top right to bottom left
        bingo = true; // until proven otherwise
        for (int c = (x-1); c >= 0 && bingo; c--)
        {
            for (int r = 0; r < y && bingo; r++)
            {
                int number = bingoCard[r, c];
                bingo = userNmr.Contains(number);
            }
        }
        if (bingo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Diagonal Bingo from Top Right to Bottom Left.");         
            return true;
        }

        // no bingos were found!
        return false; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, finally got it to work!